# C++ Fatal Error C1017

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have am getting:

> **fatal error C1017: invalid integer constant expression**

with the following piece of code:

```
#if V1>0
//do stuff
#endif
```

V1 is defined as follows at the top of the .cpp file:

```
#define V3 UINT32
#define V4  sizeof(V3)
#define V1 (V2 % V4)
```

V2 is defined as follows:

```
const int V2 = 256;
```

Can anybody see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
#define V2 256
```

instead of

```
const int V2 = 256;
```

Edit: There is some good reason you're doing preprocessor macros instead of just regular branching, right?

Edit 2: As someone else pointed out, the preprocessor does not accept sizeof statements, as these are handled by the compiler.  Your options are to use a programmatic if statement (as opposed to a preprocessor one) or to use the real value of the size expression (which would involve hardcoding the size.  However, since it's a UINT32, I don't think it will ever be anything other than 4.

Comment: So even though NUM_BYTES is #define as a constant at the top of the file, because it is defined using TOTAL which is declared as 'const int' we get the error?

Comment: Yep.  If you were using a regular if statement (not a preprocessor one) you would be able to leave TOTAL defined as a variable.

Comment: Macro expansion is done before any compilation. You end up with `#if (16 % sizeof(UINT32))>0`, but `sizeof` is determined by the compiler, not the preprocessor, so the preprocessor cannot evaluate the result of the `>` operator.

Comment: So all places where NUM_BYTES is used are actually broken then because its not evaluated?, for instance its used in some calculations that dontinvolve the preprocessor in other parts of the file.

Comment: if it's used at compile time, it's fine.  It just resolves to the string `(TOTAL % sizeof(UINT32))` which the compiler understands (but the preprocessor doesn't).

Answer (score 4):

Preprocessing takes place before compilation. That means you can't use compile-time concepts (i.e. `const int TOTAL = 16;`) during preprocessing. The preprocessor has no knowledge of variables in your program (even `const`).

Instead of using a `#define` for the constant as well, as Wug suggested, a cleaner solution would be:

```
typedef UINT32 TARGET_TYPE;
const int TARGET_TYPE_SIZE = sizeof(TARGET_TYPE);
const int TOTAL = 16;
const int NUM_BYTES = (TOTAL % TARGET_TYPE_SIZE);
```